# Compare and swap library in C++ explain(seems not work to me)

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, x86, atomic

When I read the x86 implement, the compare and swap function seems to look like this:

```
template <typename T>
bool compare_and_swap(T *dst, T exp, T desired)
{ // do atomically
 if (*dst == exp) {
   *dst = desired;
   return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

I'm wondering if more than one thread goes to `if (*dst==exp)`, and since that `exp` has not be changed, they can both pass the if statement and execute `*dst = desired`. I'm wondering if it is so, why would the function work? Seems that it do not stop other thread to change the data?
Can someone kindly tell how this function work?

Comment: Per the standard unless these types are `std::atomic` types this is not safe.  You need synchronization to avoid data races.  It doesn't matter how the hardware handles things.  Your code can be changed by the compiler/hardware to become something different if you don't use synchronization.

Comment: The probability that your scenario happens is likely to be very weak, but this doesn't means that this function is correct. Note that the way it is called is unknown to us and we can't answer precisely...

Comment: You are assuming that the function must be thread safe. But must it?

Comment: What is "the x86 implement"? And if the function only *seems to* look like that, what does it really look like?

Comment: A good compiler may use some test-and-set instruction. In such a case that code can be correct.

Comment: My interpretation is that the comment says "this whole function happens as one atomic operation", and the given code is not the implementation itself but an informal description of the effect (modulo the atomicity). But it's entirely unclear whether this interpretation is correct because the question does not provide the context/source needed.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, I actually read this on this https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~stephentu/presentations/workshop.pdf page30, it does make sense if all function happened at one atomic operation.